# Eigen Library: Compiler error when passing Block reference to templated function

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I am getting a compilation error when trying to call templated functions with arguments that are Eigen references.

For example, consider the following simplified example:

```html
 template <typename derived>
 inline void fcn(Eigen::MatrixBase<derived> &M){
     // ...
 
     M.template block<3,3>(0,0) = something here
     // ...
 
 }
  
// I get compiler errors when trying to call this function as follows:
 
Eigen::MatrixXd A(100,100);
 
// call the above function with a Block as an argument
 fcn(A.block<9,6>(10,10));
```

The compiler complains that I am trying to instantiate a non-const reference with an object passed by value (if my undersdanding of the following is correct):

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 9, 6, false> >&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 9, 6, false> >’
```

If I try to declare the argument of fcn as `const` then I am getting an error when I try to modify it inside the function.

The only solution I've found to work to fix this issue is to declare the arument of the function to be a `const &`, and then to use `const_cast` to "remove the const qualifier" when accessing `M` inside the function.

But this is hacky and I makes the code extremely messy. Am I missing some obvious solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in c++ you cannot bind a temporary object (here the proxy object returned by `.block()`) to a non-const reference. The solution is to name it:

```
auto A_block = A.block<9,6>(10,10);
fcn(A_block);
```